# d3.js - Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'exit'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a series of line after every 5 seconds by changing the lineData array which I feed to the d3 line function:

Here are the excerpts of the code relevant:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("id", "svgMain")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(drag);

var lines = svg.append("g")
      .attr("id", "lines");

function changingLines() {
      lines.selectAll("line")
        .data(lineData)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d, i) { console.log(d[0][0]); return d[0][0];})
        .attr("y1", function(d, i) { console.log(d[0][1]); return d[0][1];})
        .attr("x2", function(d, i) { return d[1][0];})
        .attr("y2", function(d, i) { return d[1][1];})
        .style("stroke", "#000")
        .style("stroke-width", "0.5")
        .attr("class", "lines");

     lines.selectAll("line").exit().remove();
     setTimeout(changingLines, 2000);
 }
```

I call the function changingLines() once every 2  seconds with different values for lineData array.

I get the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'exit**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got a couple related problems with this code actually. When you call `changingLines`, the only elements which will have their attributes updated are the elements in the `enter` selection (calling `.enter()` returns the `enter` selection`).

Remember that by default, `.data()` will only add elements to the `enter` selection if there are new elements in the array you pass into it, e.g.

```
// Old data array:
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// New data array:
var newData = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

/*
The first 4 elements in newData will replace the first 4 elements of oldData.
The number of new elements (which will be in the enter() selection) is only 1.
*/
```

What you should do is save the join computed by your `data` call, and use it to individually access `enter`, `exit`, and `update` selections.

```
var linesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("id", "lines");

function changingLines() {

    /* Compute the data join */
    var lines = linesContainer.selectAll("line").data(lineData);

    /* Enter */
    lines.enter().append("line");

    /* Exit */
    lines.exit().remove();

    /* Update */
    lines
         .attr("x1", function(d, i) { console.log(d[0][0]); return d[0][0];})
         .attr("y1", function(d, i) { console.log(d[0][1]); return d[0][1];})
         .attr("x2", function(d, i) { return d[1][0];})
         .attr("y2", function(d, i) { return d[1][1];})
         .style("stroke", "#000")
         .style("stroke-width", "0.5")
         .attr("class", "lines");

    setTimeout(changingLines, 2000);
}
```

This will remove old `line` elements and add new `line` elements to before it updates the attributes and styles.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter

> **The enter selection merges into the update selection when you append
>   or insert.** This approach reduces code duplication between enter and
>   update. Rather than applying operators to both the enter and update
>   selection separately, you can now apply them to the update selection
>   after entering the nodes. In the rare case that you want to run
>   operators only on the updating nodes, you can run them on the update
>   selection before entering new nodes.

This should also fix your problem with not being able to call `exit()`. When you were calling `lines.selectAll("line")` the second time, you were creating a new selection, and therefore you wouldn't have access to the selections computed when you did your previous join.

Read, and reread this article: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/